# twitter api rate limit issue

Tags: python, tweepy

I’m trying to query tweet using tweepy by tweet ids (about 2300 ids)
but i can only query around 185 ids each time and then have to wait for 15mins, which means that 2300 ids will take about 3 hrs to complete.

the api im using is:

```
consumer_key = 'xxxxxx'
consumer_secret = 'xxxxxx'
access_token = 'xxxxxxxx'
access_secret = 'xxxxxx'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth,wait_on_rate_limit=True,wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)
```

then loop through each id in tweet_id with api.get_status method

I did google around and turns out that possibly app-only queries allows more request within 15min windows, can anyone please point out how can i make an app-only request with tweepy ?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `statuses_lookup` ([tweepy docs](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.5.0/api.html#API.statuses_lookup), [twitter docs](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/post-and-engage/api-reference/get-statuses-lookup)) instead, and pass up to 100 ids per call. The limit with using this method is 300 requests according to the [rate limits page](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/rate-limits). That is, you could get 300x100=30000 tweets before reaching the window limit and having to wait for 15 minutes. Your 2300 ids would be collected really quick.

Hope it helps

**UPDATE** to answer comment:

From the Twitter docs:

> If a requested Tweet is unknown or deleted, then that Tweet will not be returned in the results list, unless the map parameter is set to true, in which case it will be returned with a value of null.

So you won't really get an error, but you may not get the tweet. So you would want to compare the returned results against your ID list to see which tweet was not returned.

Comment: this looks promising, I will try and get back here,  but how to handle error if it happens to one of ids while query in this case

Comment: ok, so that means i can't see what error msg returned, but still I can get the ids that did have error by comparing with original list, then i can run each of ids in error individually. great, i will try now

Comment: got error: has error: Twitter error response: status code = 414, i sent one request with 100 ids in it

Comment: 414 means the URI was too long. Twitter [docs](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/post-and-engage/api-reference/get-statuses-lookup) recommend using POST in that case "You are strongly encouraged to use a POST for larger requests."

Comment: Although I'm not quite sure if you can specify the method in tweepy, let me check it out

Comment: I believe you can specify the method, just pass `method='POST'` to the `statuses_lookup` method call, let me know

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do application only authentication with tweepy 2.0

Read this: https://shogo82148.github.io/blog/2013/05/09/application-only-authentication-with-tweepy/

I hope this helped!

Comment: i found this link too, but i dont have user id, only tweet id

Comment: @ikel I think you may be out of luck then. Can you not get the user id from the tweet object? I am not very familiar with the twitter api.